# Setting layout_height equal to layout_width="match_parent" in a layout file

Tags: android

The title says it all. I need to create a square sized `View` which height depends entirely from size of the mobile devices width (`layout_width="match_parent"`).

Is it possible to specify `layout_height="...equals to width..."` from Android's .xml file or I have to do this at runtime?

Comment: Try using ratio in a Constraint Layout https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: Thanks man, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1):

You could resize the view programmatically by extending it and using your custom class in the xml instead. For example, I will extend the `ImageView` class and will return a square image(by changing the height to the size of the width):

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {


    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Allows the view to resize 
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width); //setting height same as width here
    }
}
```

As mentioned, using this class would always result in a square image, where the height is equal to the width.

To use it in layout file:

```
<com.packagename.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

However, you have to take care of cases such as the device is in landscape, this way you'll have the width much greater than the height, so the view won't fit.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this is very good answer but I think I'm gonna go with ConstraintLayout and ratio as was suggested by @JuanCruzSoler just because I think it will be better for animations, but an upvote from me for sure